# will I get a undefined reference error if I use index in Filter() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have on the front end

```
<ul>
<li><strong>list</strong> item 1 - one strong tag</li>
<li><strong>list</strong> item <strong>2</strong> -
two <span>strong tags</span></li>
<li>list item 3</li>
<li>list item 4</li>
<li>list item 5</li>
<li>list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

And I have a Jquery that does some simple filtering

```
$( "li" )
.filter(function( index ) {
return index % 3 === 2;
})
.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

My question is, will I get an undefined error with index? or index is automatically assigned to the position of each li element in the DOM? please advise.

Many thanks

Comment: `index` will be an iterator, a number that increases by one for each iteration that is done.

Comment: [Per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) you are using it correctly.  `index` is a callback argument, which jQuery itself supplies for each node handled by the function

Comment: ok, now i am clear. index is just an iterator. it has nothing to do with the DOM structure or whatsoever

Comment: How do you think could you get `undefined`? And why do you think that?

Comment: Why haven't you simply tried it out and seen that you're not getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to see if something works is to just try it. Like so:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").filter(function(index) {
      return index % 3 === 2;
    })
    .css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item 1 - one strong tag</li>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item <strong>2</strong> - two <span>strong tags</span>
  </li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you wont get an Error. You can use it like you did it. Like the docs said it. So dont worry its alright.
We can also take advantage of the index passed through the function, which indicates the 0-based position of the element within the unfiltered set of matched elements:

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return index % 3 === 2;
  })
    .css( "background-color", "red" );
```

This alteration to the code will cause the third and sixth list items to be highlighted, as it uses the modulus operator (%) to select every item with an index value that, when divided by 3, has a remainder of 2.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your code and the OP's code?

Comment: there is no difference as i said "you can use it like you did it". I just wanted to make him sure that his code is right.